# How to play dojo with sprockets in rails edge?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, dojo, sprockets

Rails 3.1 edge use sprockets to handle .js and .scss files.
Sprockets use comments to deal with dependencies.

I put the three folders (dojo dijit dojox) in vendor/assets/javascripts.
Then add a line in app/assets/javascripts/application.js
    //= require dojo/dojo
    console.log(dojo);

Now dojo has been merged into application.js.
But dojo has dependency system itself. When I require more dojo modules. It cannot find the right path.
    dojo.require("dojox.grid.DataGrid");
    // Error in webkit console: Error: Could not load 'dojox.grid.DataGrid'; last tried '../dojox/grid/DataGrid.js'
    // Error in rails server log: Started GET "/undefined../dojox/grid/DataGrid.js" for 127.0.0.1 at Sat Apr 16 01:26:05 +0800 2011

These are two different dependency systems. How can I put them together?

Answer (score 1):

`dojo.js` doesn't take too naturally to being renamed.  This is because part of Dojo's initialization process involves searching through the DOM for the script tag responsible for loading itself.  It does this for two reasons:

1. Determine its `baseUrl` if not already specified
2. Pick up any `djConfig` (or `data-dojo-config` in 1.6+) properties specified in the script tag itself

When it searches for this script tag, it looks for one with `src` set to `dojo.js` or `dojo.xd.js`; it's not finding it in your case, thus the failures.

It should be possible to work around both of these issues, by specifying `djConfig` (or `dojoConfig` in 1.6+) fully programmatically in another `script` tag *before* the one that loads Dojo, and by specifying `baseUrl` manually in these config properties.

For example, if your `application.js` were in `vendor/assets/javascripts` as referred to in your original post, you could try doing this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //if you're using 1.5 or earlier, use djConfig instead of dojoConfig
    var dojoConfig = {
        //note that baseUrl points to the folder containing dojo.js, therefore the dojo folder
        baseUrl: 'vendor/assets/javascripts/dojo/'
    };
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/assets/javascripts/application.js"></script>
```

For more information on dojo config settings: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/djConfig.html  (in fact, that page actually has a note under baseUrl specifically about renamed `dojo.js`.)

Comment: This issus is more complex because gem 'sprockets' and is enable default rails master branch `config.assets.enabled = true`. rails 3.1.0.beta deal with .js file like this: Merge `vendor/assets/javascripts/jquery.js` into `application.js`. Merge `app/assets/javascripts/**/*.js` into `application.js`. In layout .erb file include `application.js`. It check dependencies by comments. IMO, these two place use for custom script not exists frameworks. [Specifying dependencies with the require directive](http://getsprockets.org/installation_and_usage#specifying_dependencies_with_the_require_directive)

Comment: In fact. rails 3.1.0.beta deal with stylesheets by the same way. Even images. Sprockets merge javascripts stylesheets images under app/assets into one file. If these file 'require' another that not be at here. It will search from vendor/assets. Most frameworks cannot follow this rule. Dojo put styles and images in module subfolder. So I think, we cannot put frameworks in to these two place. We must put them under public/ as static files.

Comment: Look like there is a SprocketsController or sprockets middleware. Rails 3.1.0.beta use it to handle all incoming assets request.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the dojo files into a `dojo/scripts` directory under `/vendor/assets/javascripts`. In the dojo directory, create a dojo.js file in the `dojo` directory and put `//= provide "scripts"` in that file.

Then in your `application.js` file put `//= require <dojo>`. Check out the Sprockets site http://getsprockets.org/ for info but that should work.

The docs aren't out for Rails 3.1 and the asset pipeline yet so a lot of this stuff is kind of trying to figure out on your own.

Answer (score 0):

Umm... why are you placing your javascripts in `vendor` and app rather than `public/javascripts`? you have include anything in `public/javascripts` with `=javascript_include_tag('path_to_javascript')` where path_to_javascript would be `"dojo/DataGrid"` for `public/javascripts/dojo/DataGrid.js`

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Comment: You can create a new rails *3.1.0.beta* project. [Sprockets](http://getsprockets.org/) is default gem in Gemfile and enable asset pipeline default:

Comment: Ah, sorry about that... You should be able to rename the files so dependencies are loaded in order as they are included alphabetically, no?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's maybe a bit late but I could help someone else.

[I finally made it work and posted the explanations here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370646/how-to-use-dojo-toolkit-with-rails-3-1-asset-pipeline-and-coffeescript/7826777#7826777)