# How to use dojo toolkit with rails 3.1 asset pipeline and coffeescript?

Tags: dojo, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

I'm trying to use dojo-toolkit as the JS framework on a rails 3.1 app, but I'm struggling to incorporate the dojo require structure with the sprockets require and coffeescript. It seems dojo expects the JS files on the disk, but I guess they're created on the fly from coffeescript.

Wondering if anyone has an idea of how the two require-s can co-exist.

Answer (score 7):

I recently had to install dojo with rails 3.1 and the asset pipeline. Here are the steps I followed to make it work:

**1/ Include Dojo**

Put the dojo SDK under vendor/assets/javascripts so you get the dojo, dijit and dojox folder in it. Include it in your template:

```
= javascript_include_tag "dojo/dojo", :'data-dojo-config' => %Q(baseUrl: '/assets/dojo/', modulePaths: {modules: '/assets/modules', widgets: '/assets/widgets'})
```

Don't forget the leading '/' on assets!

You can use the [Google CDN with a fallback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7796643/conditional-javascript-require-in-the-asset-pipeline):

```
script var djConfig = { baseUrl: '/assets/dojo/', modulePaths: {modules: '/assets/modules', widgets: 'widgets'} };
= javascript_include_tag "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6.1/dojo/dojo.xd.js"
script ="typeof(dojo) === \"undefined\" && document.write(unescape('%3Cscript src=\"#{asset_path('dojo/dojo')}\"%3E%3C/script%3E'));".html_safe
```

The first line set your [djConfig](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/dojo_config/). The second actually requires dojo from Google. The third is the fallback.

---

**2/ Include your base file**

Remove all "require" in your app/assets/javascripts/application.js and put something like that (for instance):

```
dojo.provide("myapp");
```

---

**3/ Play with dojo.require**

In the djConfig in 1/, I set the modulePaths, custom them to what you want. In my exemple, you would have those two where you can put your files:

- app/assets/javascripts/modules/
- app/assets/javascripts/widgets/

If I want to require modules/test.js, I just do:

```
dojo.require("modules.test");
```

---

**4/ Use coffeescript and ERB**

Just add the right extension and start right erb, like described in the [Rails documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html).

I hope it helps you!

Comment: New to ruby. Where exactly do I put `= javascript_include_tag "dojo/dojo", :'data-dojo-config' => %Q(baseUrl: '/assets/dojo/', modulePaths: {modules: '/assets/modules', widgets: '/assets/widgets'})`? Where is this template?

Comment: In Rails it would be in your `/views/layout/application.html.erb` file