# Getting Dojo to Work with Ruby on Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dojo

I'm porting my symfony app to Ruby on Rails 4.2.0. My setup works fine in symfony. There is [this old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370646/how-to-use-dojo-toolkit-with-rails-3-1-asset-pipeline-and-coffeescript) on how to use dojo with RoR, but it uses deprecated code.

In my application.html.erb I have

```
<script>dojoConfig = {async: true}</script>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.3/dojo/dojo.js'%>
```

I replaced the symfony wrappers with Rails ones. I also changed the dojo version. I was using 1.9.1. Rails generates this html:

```
<script>
dojoConfig = {async: true}
</script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.3/dojo/dojo.js">
```

The last line is followed by a bunch of compressed javascript and the close script tag in Firebug.

I didn't make any changes in my home/index.html.erb where I'm testing this code. In app/assets/javaascipts/home.js, I have:

```
//require(["dojo/dom", "dojo/ready", "dijit/Tooltip"], function(dom, ready, Tooltip)
define(["dojo/dom", "dojo/ready", "dijit/Tooltip"], function(dom, ready, Tooltip)
{
ready(function()
{
var head = "<div class='footnote-text'>";
var tail = "</div>";
var fnt1 = head + dom.byId("fnb1").innerHTML + tail;
var fnt2 = head + dom.byId("fnb2").innerHTML + tail;
var fnt4 = head + dom.byId("fnb4").innerHTML + tail;

new Tooltip({ connectId: ["footnote1"],position:["after","above","below"],label: fnt1 });
new Tooltip({ connectId: ["footnote2"],position:["after","above","below"],label: fnt2 });
new Tooltip({ connectId: ["footnote4"],position:["after","above","below"],label: fnt4 });
new Tooltip({ connectId: ["footnote5"],position:["after","above","below"],label: fnt4 });
});
});
//require(["dojo/dom", "dojo/ready", "dijit/Dialog"], function(dom, ready, Dialog){
define(["dojo/dom", "dojo/ready", "dijit/Dialog"], function(dom, ready, Dialog){
ready(function(){
var fnt3 = dom.byId("fnb3").innerHTML;

myDialog = new Dialog({
  title: "Contact Me",
  content: fnt3,
  style: "width: 300px"
});
});
});
```

The commented out require lines are what I use in my symfony app. As you can see, I replaced them with define as described on the dojo site. When I run it, I get the following error on the Firebug console:

```
ReferenceError: define is not defined
...define(["dojo/dom", "dojo/ready", "dijit/Tooltip"], function(dom, ready, Tooltip
```

If I used require instead of define, I get require is not defined.

**Update**

I tried installing dojo into the app and made some progress. I copied the download from dojo to vendor/assets/javascript/dojo. The dojo directory contains the subdirectories dojo, dojox, and digit

I then added

```
//= require dojo/dojo/dojo.js
```

to app/assets/javascript/application.js. I also changed the define back to require in the home.js file. When I reloaded the page, I got an error complaining that it couldn't find Tooltip. I then added:

```
//= require dojo/dijit/Tooltip.js
```

On reload it complained about a bunch of other missing js files. This is the same problem I had using symfony, which is why I went to the google image. How can I get to rails to search for the files in the vendor directories? This is one of the errors:

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://amcolan.loc/dijit/_base/manager.js"
```

**Update 2**

Since require_tree worked for app assets, I thought it might work to vendor as well. I added

```
//= require_tree ../../../vendor/assets/javascripts/dojo
```

to my application.js file. When I reloaded the page, it took about a minute. My guess is that it's loading everything in the dojo directory tree, which is not surprising. The page load completed without any errors. When I hovered over a tooltip item (the purpose of the code is to show tooltips), Firebug cranked out about two thousand errors and quit. All the errors appear to be "ReferenceError: define is not defined"

**Update 3**

I went back to using the googleapi. My application.html.erb header looks like this

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title><%= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : "American Colonial Ancestors" %></title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <script>dojoConfig = {async: true}</script>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.3/dojo/dojo.js'%>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
```

I reversed the order of the javascript includes. The page reloaded without errors. The tooltip doesn't work, but it doesn't generate any errors when I hover over an item. I put a bad statement in the home.js code and it came up on the console so I know the code is being parsed. I may just have a bug in my page setup.

Comment: Closing `</script>` seems to be missing for `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.3/dojo/dojo.js">`. This maybe causing the `dojo.js` not to load. The `dojo.js` contains the definition of `define` and `require`. `define()` call is for defining modules and `Require()` is for loading the modules. You need to use `require()` instead of `define()`

Comment: As mentioned, I didn't include all the generated code. Also mentioned, I get the same result if I use require in place of define. Did you mean somewhere other than I indicated?

Comment: how is the `home.js` being called from the `index.html`. It would better if you could post the entire code. somehow the require and define modules are not being loaded and hence the `ReferenceError: define is not defined`

Comment: I got past that error and have have updated the post to reflect that. As I understand it, home.js is being included because of //= require_tree .
in the application.js file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be more than one way to get Dojo toolkit to work with Ruby on Rails. This is the easiest if not the most efficient way. This works in Rails 4.2.0. I would imagine it would work in other versions as well.

In views/layouts/application.html.erb add the following prior to the inclusion of the site scripts:

```
<script>dojoConfig = {async: true}</script>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.3/dojo/dojo.js'%>
```

Change the version to the latest or to which ever one you want to use. Here I'm using version 1.10.3. The dojo site says there are other CDN's (Content Delivery Network) for the source code. I'm using google as it was in their example.  Here are the pertinent parts of my head section:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.3/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" %>
  <script>dojoConfig = {async: true}</script>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.3/dojo/dojo.js'%>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= content_for :page_script %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
```

If you are going to use any of the toolkit's dialog boxes, tooltips, etc, you will need to include a stytlesheet by adding something like this:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.3/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" %>
```

Change the version and the theme to your own requirements. Here I'm using the claro theme. You can see it in my head section above. I don't think placement is critical. You also need to declare your theme class in the body statement. Here's mine:

```
<body class="claro">
```

An [older post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370646/how-to-use-dojo-toolkit-with-rails-3-1-asset-pipeline-and-coffeescript) on the subject had different javascript formatting. I don't think anything special is needed. Here's an example of a working script:

```
require(["dojo/dom", "dojo/ready", "dijit/Tooltip"], function(dom, ready, Tooltip)
{
  ready(function()
  {
    var head = "<div class='footnote-text'>";
    var tail = "</div>";
    var fnt1  = head + dom.byId("fnb1").innerHTML + tail;
    var fnt2  = head + dom.byId("fnb2").innerHTML + tail;

    new Tooltip({connectId: ["footnote1"], position:["after","above","below"], label: fnt1 });
    new Tooltip({connectId: ["footnote2"], position:["after","above","below"], label: fnt2 });
  });
});
```

As mentioned in my question, I tried placing the Dojo Toolkit source in vendor/assets/javascript. Starting with with version 1.7, dojo started using Asynchronous Module Definition (AMD). It may be the case that the AMD loader is incompatible with the Rails pre-compile feature. I don't know enough about it to say for sure.